# Quote PDF generated from Community Page is blank

Tags: pdf, quote

I am trying to automate generating Quote PDF Documents. My goal is to create a button, which creates Opportunity, Quote and QuoteDocument. I am using such code for generating QuoteDocument:

```
String quoteUrl = 'https://britenet-10a-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?id=';
quoteUrl += quoteId;
quoteUrl += '&headerHeight=190&footerHeight=188&summlid=' +
quoteUrl += templateId +
quoteUrl += '#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&zoom=90';
System.debug('quoteurl ' + quoteUrl);
PageReference pg = new PageReference(quoteUrl);
QuoteDocument quotedoc = new QuoteDocument();
Blob b = pg.getContentAsPDF();
quotedoc.Document = b;
quotedoc.QuoteId = quoteId;
insert quotedoc;
```

In this code `quoteId` and `templateId` are ids for existing Quote and QuoteTemplate objects. Quote is being created earlier in the same method. Opportunity and Quote object are being created perfectly. Right now I am able to create PDF Documents with existing content via Anonymous Apex, but if I try do to this using that button in my Community Page as a Partner Community User, then it only generates blank documents. I also tried to move that code into a future method, but then it doesn't create any document at all. Could you help me with that problem? Every response would be appreciated.

Comment: The `pg.getContentAsPDF()` call runs in a separate transaction, so moving that to until after the current transaction commits (completes) is normally necessary and `@future` is one way to do that. Not sure why you were not. successful; suggest you pursue that approach and debug.

Comment: I moved the logic for generating QuoteDocument to the separate ```@future``` method which can be invoked by ```@AuraEnabled``` method. Now, Opportunity and Quote objects are generated in another method which runs first. Then QuoteDocument should be created. I managed to generate non-empty pdf document, but sadly it is possible only if I am logged as admin user. It turns out that every other Partner Community user has no level of access necessary to perform such operation. I received INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY error. Maybe there are some permission sets for that?

Comment: Take a look at "Sharing Settings"; the "Default External Access" (applies to your community case) is private and that is likely a cause of your problem.